Print one time in a C function that uses recursion without using a global variable
I have to print One time in a C function that use recursion.
The issue is to print End1 at the end of func1 (after recursion call line) 1 time and not more than 1 time:
to do this i created fend1() that I equipped with a global variable
The following code is my actual solution but I wish to get the same goal,
without using any global variable.
#include<stdio.h>

int cntg1 = 1;
int fend1(){
    if(cntg1 < 2){
        printf("\nEnd1");
        cntg1++;
    }
    return 0;
}
void func1(int i){
    
    if(i == 6) return; // Base Case
    printf("%d ", i);
    func1(i + 1);
    fend1(); // <<< this is factory new
}


int main()
{
    func1(1); // *
    return 0;
}

The following link open a new website page click here to view the code run.

As I anticipate, I wish to get the same goal (print 1 time after recursion),
without using any global variable.
I asked before about a similar problem (here can be found the other question) and according to the Problem this above receive the higest score, but I have to find a better solution.


Pass your cntg1 as an extra parameter to you functions, or some other parameter to flag that it should print stuff.

from main() to both functions?

you can move your int cntg1 = 1; into the function and declare it static

...and how can I increment it in fend1()?

You have a base case. Just use it
void func1(int i){
    
    if(i == 6) 
    {
        printf("\nEnd1");
        return; // Base Case
    }
    printf("%d ", i);
    func1(i + 1);
//    fend1(); // <<< this is factory new
}

Pay attention to that the function will have unspecified behavior when will be called with an argument greater than 6.
And using the magic number 6 within the function definition is a bad idea.

may be, but the call is Fixed (only to focus the Problem, I think);
then here is the 2nd line of description: "The issue is to print End1 at the end of func1 (1 time and not more than 1 time): to do this i created fend1() that I equipped with a global variable" but you right is better I add "after recursion call". Thanks for the notice.

You can modify the func1 to return a flag indicating whether the End1 message has been printed or not. Try sth. like this:
#include <stdio.h>

int func1(int i) {
    // Base Case
    if (i == 6) {
        return 0;
    }

    printf("%d ", i);
    int printed_end1 = func1(i + 1);

    // Print "End1" only if it hasn't been printed yet
    if (printed_end1 == 0) {
        printf("\nEnd1");
        return 1;
    }

    return printed_end1;
}

int main() {
    func1(1);
    return 0;
}


Kindly, why printed_end1 is  == 0 ? And when it became > 0 ?

Cause, according to me, if is 0 it remains 0 until the return 0 .

Another common way to handle things like this (albeit unnecessary in your case) is to separate your function into two parts:
void func1_(int i){
    if (i == 6) return;
    printf("%d ", i);
    func1_(i + 1);
}

void func1(int i){
    func1_(i);
    printf("\nEnd1");
}


You don't need an extra function or any global varibles. Just conditionally let func1 call itself. Since printing "End1 at the end of func1 (1 time and not more than 1 time)" seems important, just put it in the else case:
#include <stdio.h>

void func1(int i) {
    printf("%d ", i);

    if (i < 5)
        func1(i + 1);
    else
        puts("\nEnd1"); // at the end of func1, only printed once
}

int main(void) {
    func1(1); 
}

